# Why is push() not working inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, dynamic-arrays

I have some code:

```
  var cdata = [];

  d3.text("tests.info", function(text) {
    var data = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        cdata.push({key: d[0],values: []}
      );
    });
  });
```

It's reading in a CSV file and then looping though the lines before adding them into the array. I've used logs to see that the data is getting added correctly so this is fine.

The  issue is that if I try and access the array afterwards, it is empty, as if the data was never added (although I know this isn't true).

I think it is something to do with scoping, but I thought that `push()` should work in this way regardless.

Comment: It's not scoping, it's asynchronous behavior. Code immediately after the `d3.text()` call executes before the callback function is run. Add a `console.log(cdata)` inside the callback function after the `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `console.log` inside a timeout function, or put a button that display cdata's content and you'll see that it is not empty. As Pointy said, what happen is:

- You declare cdata
- You start loading `test.info`
- You display cdata's content
- `test.info` is loaded, you start looping and putting data in your array

Comment: Yeah this makes sense. It works by putting the code that uses cdata into the callback function as well, thereby only running when it's loaded. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You can make a function and call it inside your callback function which would be easier to read, but I don't see another way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `cdata`:

```
d3.text("tests.info", function(text) {
  var data = d3.csv.parseRows(text), cdata = [];
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    cdata.push({key: d[0],values: []};
  });
  return cdata;
});
```

Consider also just doing

```
d3.text("tests.info", function(text) {
  return d3.csv.parseRows(text).map(function(d) {
    return {key: d[0], values: []};
  });
});
```